# Video recorded with Kickflip example doesn´t work

Tags: ios

I am running the example project for iOS and I'm experiencing two problems:

1) The block method to get the stream URL is never called.

```
[Kickflip presentBroadcasterFromViewController:self ready:^(KFStream stream) {
if (stream.streamURL) 
{
    DDLogInfo(@"Stream is ready at URL: %@", stream.streamURL);
}
} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError error){
    if (!success) {
       DDLogError(@"Error setting up stream: %@", error);
    } else {
       DDLogInfo(@"Done broadcasting");
    }
  }];
```

2) When I try reproduce the videos recorded with the app, in the web page, appears a "Buffering" message, but the video is never reproduce.

Comment: @David, i am experiencing exactly the same problem. did you figure out the problem?

Comment: @Usama this wasn't my question, I just edited it (formatted the code in it).